# Duplicate database entries with passenger_min_instances when I have timer in the application

Tags: mongodb, meteor, passenger

I'm running a meteor application with Phusion Passenger & Nginx. To have better response to end users. I have set up `passenger_min_instances` to `3`. In the application, there is a timer to process some data and store in the MongoDB. I found that when there are some users visiting user site, it will write multiple entries to MongoDB. Is there any way to avoid this? Or is this not cause for generating multiple entires? The timer is setup in the server startup block so it keeps running forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up adding unique indexes to the collections to avoid this but I do think this is kinda strange behavior.